# Foreign Key Cascade Delete not working as expected in OpenJPA / Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

Can anyone explain why I am not seeing the expected results with OpenJPA's @ForeignKey annotation calling for Cascade Delete?

I have reduced this to a small test case with two JPA Entity classes "Parent" and "Child" related by OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships, respectively. Child's relationship to Parent is annotated with the OpenJPA @ForeignKey annotation, specifying that deletes should cascade.

The mappings and SchemaFactory settings are set to respect foreign keys.

The database correctly reflects the foreign key relationship.

But, in a test case, when I delete the parent, the child does not delete.

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- See this: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58527-transaction-type-quot-JTA-quot-quot-RESOURCE_LOCAL-quot -->

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="entitiesTestPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>entitiesDsJtaTest</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>entitiesDsNonJtaTest</non-jta-data-source>
        <validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
        <properties>
         <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"  />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)"/> 
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="slf4j" />
            <property name="openjpa.LockTimeout" value="5000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Parent class:

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends DbEntity {

    public Parent()  {
    }

    private String name;

    public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return this.name;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",  fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        if (child.getParent() != this) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Attempt to add a Child to a usage point that does not own it.");
        }
        this.getChildren().add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        if (child.getParent() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Attempt to remove a Child that stil belongs to a Parent.");
        }
        this.children.remove(child);
    }

    public boolean hasChild(Child child) {
        return this.children.contains(child);
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

}
```

The child class:

```
@Entity
    public class Child extends DbEntity {

    public Child() {
    }

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return this.name;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @ForeignKey(deleteAction = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, updateAction = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
    private Parent parent = null;


    public Parent getParent() {
    return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        Parent old = this.getParent();
        if (parent != old) {
            if (old != null) {
                this.parent = null;
                old.removeChild(this);
            }
            this.parent = parent;
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.addChild(this);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The test case (run with Arquillian)

```
@Test
public void testCascadeDeleteParent() throws IllegalStateException, SecurityException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, RollbackException, SystemException, NotSupportedException {
    Child child = new Child();
    em.persist(child);
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    em.persist(parent);
    child.setParent(parent);
    long id1 = child.getId();
    // Child is manaaged.
    Assert.assertNotNull("child has no ID?", id1); 
    long id2 = parent.getId();
    Assert.assertNotNull("parent has no ID?", id2);
    this.em.remove(parent);
    Parent p2 = this.em.find(Parent.class, id2);
    Assert.assertNull("Parent should be gone; we deleted it. ", p2);
    Child s1 = this.em.find(Child.class, id1);
    Assert.assertNull("Child should be gone after Parent is deleted.", s1);
}
```

The database definitely has the foreign key action:

```
test=# \d+ dbentity;
                                Table "public.dbentity"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id        | bigint                 | not null  | plain    |              | 
 version   | integer                |           | plain    |              | 
 dtype     | character varying(255) |           | extended |              | 
 name      | character varying(255) |           | extended |              | 
 parent_id | bigint                 |           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "dbentity_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dbentity_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES dbentity(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "dbentity" CONSTRAINT "dbentity_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES dbentity(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE
Has OIDs: no

test=#
```

The top of the stack trace, for whatever it's worth:

```
   java.lang.AssertionError: Child should be gone after Parent is deleted. expected null, but was:<com.testco.Child@5bfcf845>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotNull(Assert.java:664)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:646)
        at com.testco.ChildIntegrationTest.testCascadeDeleteParent(ChildIntegrationTest.java:138)
```

Comment: You have the annotation on the Child's relationship to its parent.  That means if you delete the child, you are telling it to also delete the parent.  Maybe put it in the Parent entity to see the expected results.  Also, why not just use JPA's cascade options instead of OpenJPA specific annotations?

Comment: The reason for not using JPA's cascade option is because of the issue with top-down cascade deletes causing an OptimisticLockingException, see for example https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-39.

Are you 100% sure about the proper location for the @ForeignKey annotation? Everything I have encountered suggests that it should be on the child, i.e., on the relation that actually has the foreign key. The parent has no foreign key.

Comment: I'm talking about your delete action option, not the foreignKey definition itself.  I'm not familar with OpenJPA, but if it is like the JPA cascade option (which is likely), then it applies from Child to Parent, not the other way around like you seem to expect.  Try deleting a child and see if its parent gets removed.  If so, use JPA cascade delete on the parent to child relationship instead.

Comment: Also, my quick read of  OPENJPA-39 and its workarounds has me believing it is a constraint issue, not an optimistic locking issue.  If so, you can still use JPA cascading options, you just need the OpenJPA annotation to let OpenJPA know there is a constraint on the relation so that it orders deletes accordingly.

Comment: The ForeignKey deleteAction "Cascade" terminology is unfortunate because it confuses people -- it is not like JPA's cascade option. JPA's cascade option is specified on the parent. The ForeignKey deleteAction is specified on the child, the table that contains the foreign key. The semantics are, "What should the DB do when you try to delete a record (from parent) that would violate the foreign key referential integrity?"  The options are, approximately, "Throw an exception," "Set the foreign key to null," and "Delete the child record."